# Add uid to existing menu link

Tags: 8, redirection, navigation

I have a custom menu MyMenu and I have four menu items. 
What I want to do is to add the current uid as a parameter at the end of the link.

In D7 I could use menu_tokens module which is not available on D8.

I tried to create a routing file in my custom module.

So in my routing file MY_MODULE.routing.yml I added :

```
MY_MODYLE.my_applications_redirect:
  path: '/my-applications'
  defaults:
_controller: '\Drupal\MY_MODULE\Controller\MyApplicationController::redirect_to_my_applications'
```

And in MyApplicationController.php :

```
namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
 * A controller that redirects to the my applications page.
 */
 class MyApplicationController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function redirect_to_my_applications() {

    global $base_url;
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $path = '/my-applications/'. $user->id();

    $response = new RedirectResponse($base_url . $path);
    $response->send();
  }

}
```

Also in the menu I have set the path to /my-applications.

Do I miss something?

PS. The "my-applications" page is a panel page.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from the [menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) that the module has a pre-released version for drupal 8 as development release, so maybe you could try it out or at least search in its code to find a way to accomplish your needs.

I have recently built a drupal 7 website and i have used the [menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) to create a hover over drop down usermenu with username and profile picture.

See image below (i drawed in black on top of it because the site in not yet online)
[image: hover over drop down menu]

If you like, i can right back small tutorial on how i achieved that !

Comment: Thank you but the menu token module (dev) hasn't been updated since 2013 and also I work on d8 which is different than d7.